# Отправка формы на GoogleScript

Tags: http, post, google-apps-script

Пытаюсь написать на GS скрипт, который пинговал бы произвольный хост с помощью внешнего ресурса. В качестве ресурса выбрал *http://ping.eu/ping*

Разобрался, что вроде как по хорошему надо писать нечто такое:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://ping.eu/ping/", pingEuOptions);
```

, где pingEuOptions примерно такой:

```
var pingEuOptions =
  {
    "method" : "post",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1"
  };
```

Но в результате получаю страницу с пустой формой, без вывода. Единственный полезный результат - IP, с которого туда стучался Google. Если я всё правильно понимаю, отправка метода POST или GET (в коде страницы написано что используется post) на нужный адрес с данными формы должна вызывать submit и ответ, который я получаю, если тыкаю на соответствующую кнопку в браузере, но тут, похоже, submit не происходит.

Ещё нашёл, что если заходить на *http://ping.eu/ping/action.php?host=127.0.0.1* , то выдаётся страница с заполненным полем host, но не могу найти что ещё надо дописать, чтобы у этой формы (name у неё "frm") таки выполнился submit, поэтому топчусь на том же месте.

Раньше с HTTP не работал и в GoogleScript тоже имею крайне скромный опыт, поэтому в данном вопросе могу смело назвать себя чайником. Наверняка всё решается очень просто, но до меня не доходит, и кэпа рядом нет. Добрые люди, объясните чайнику как заваривать чай через HTTP?

Comment: Нашёл, что на других подобных сервисах можно получать результат, проходя по ссылке типа *default.php?host=127.0.0.1*, но этот результат выдаётся скриптом с задержкой, зависящей от собственно пинга. А ContentText записывается в response сразу, поэтому я получаю пустой вывод.